# SignHere tabs not adding on document while creating signer recipient

Tags: docusignapi

I am creating Signer Recipient from REST C# SDK using **EnvelopesApi** "**CreateRecipient**" method. I am also putting SignHere tabs for the respective recipient on the basis of anchor text, but the tabs are not displayed in the signing email.
Am I missing anything?

Comment: Are you sure the document is 'readable' when it hits DocuSign? Try creating the envelope as a draft, accessing it though the web console, place a tag in the tagger and assign it the same Anchor Text string to see if it can be placed like that.

Comment: Also, can you post an API log of the call that's being generated, so we can see what you're doing in your code?

Comment: Need to correct in-process(sent) envelope. Scenario is that Document is already there in DocuSign, I need to create Signer with tabs on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add a recipient and its tabs then you should call below API endpoint on envelope:

```
PUT /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}?advanced_update=true
```

Req body:

```
{
    "recipients": {
      "signers": [
                     {
                        "email": "johndoe@email.com",
                        "name": "John Doe",
                        "recipientId": "1",
                        "roleName": "Signer",
                        "routingOrder": "1",
                        "tabs": {
                            "signHereTabs": [{
                                "anchorString": "spsign1"
                            }]
                        }
                    }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, will try it. Just a quick question, When we use "POST /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients" ?

Comment: Tried it but not working.Scenario is that Document is already there in DocuSign, I need to create Signer with tabs on it. If request logs can help please let me know

Comment: Yes, please edit your qs post and add request logs with pdf so that I can try to replicate it, also are you planning to add recipient to draft envelope or sent envelope?

Comment: My bad, it was giving an error due to a mismatch between RecipientId of Signer and SignerTab. But you suggestion helped. Thanks.

Comment: Just one more thing, shoud I lock envelope before correcting from API?

Comment: Can there be scenario where you will be doing updates when someone is trying to access the envelope? If yes, the you can put lock, else its not required.